# How to correctly reshape this array with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm new to arrays and the shape definitions that they have in numpy and Python. I'm trying to convert this array to this kind of format, and doing it inside a list comprehension and then converting to a numpy array is taking a huge amount of time, so I thought it would be quicker to reshape the array instead of doing my modification which speeds up the processing time. Here's the before and after:

```
   [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

What I want:

```
   [[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]],
   [[9], [8], [7], [6], [5], [4], [3], [2], [1]]]
```

I've been able to reshape each sublist successfully with a list comprehension, but I haven't been able to figure out how to reshape the entire array to have each int inside a list.

Comment: You can do `np.atleast_3d(your_array)` or---if `your_array` is a numpy array, not a list of lists---`your_array[...,None]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `arr.reshape()` :-

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]] )
arr = arr.reshape(2,9,1)
print(arr)
```

*Output*

```
[[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]
 [5]
 [6]
 [7]
 [8]
 [9]]

[[9]
[8]
[7]
[6]
[5]
[4]
[3]
[2]
[1]]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually just figured it out as you posted this haha

Comment: @ShaneSmiskol hahaha, Looks like I have posted at a good time.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at `numpy.expand_dims`, click [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) to see the official document.

```py
import numpy as np

arr=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
arr=np.array(arr)
arr=np.expand_dims(arr,axis=2)
print(arr.shape)
print(arr)
```

Then the output shoule be what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

you can use shape:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]])
x.shape = (2,9,1)
print(x)
```

output:

```
[[[1]
  [2]
  [3]
  [4]
  [5]
  [6]
  [7]
  [8]
  [9]]

 [[9]
  [8]
  [7]
  [6]
  [5]
  [4]
  [3]
  [2]
  [1]]]
```